# Refresh/reload textview from database | Button Tapped Function

Tags: ios, database, textview, refresh, reload

I have declare the textview outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageView: UITextView!
```

I have created the interface action, and place the logic:

```
@IBAction func refreshTextViewTapped(sender: UIButton) {

// logic

}
```

Reload/update textview with new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't the setText function automatically update the textview? What would you need a reload function to do if the text is already being updated?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad()
{
    setMyTextView();

    // create the button that calls your function to update the text view
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setMyTextView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void)setMyTextView()
{
    NSString *myText = // value that is returned from the database query;
    [self.myTextView setText:myText];
}
```

Comment: are you using a local database like SQLite or are you connecting to a server? In either case, you could just create a function that connects to the database, queries the info, and then calls the setText function on the textview.

Comment: i have just not memorized all of the methods, functions, and properties that are available within iOS/Xcode so I am still learning all of the documentation.

Comment: i added a code example...let me know if that helps at all